# 20-shot magazine for Lee-Enfield?

Tags: united-states, guns

Do you know where I can get a 20-shot magazine for a 1917 303 MKIII Lee-Enfield rifle?

I currently have a 10-shot magazine.  I have searched the internet and  I've seen a picture of one but have not seen one for sale. I am looking in Texas.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.gunpartscorp.com?

Comment: Close description - "Questions seeking price-shopping assistance are off-topic..." Hmm. It's not about price.

Comment: @DonBranson  given how rare these are I have changed my mind and think we should keep this open

Comment: That's got a point - ebay triggered the shopping reflex. @AlexaKirk In what location are you looking for this?

Comment: This question triggered a scope question for me, as it seems to apply to this. It might not actually apply though (don't know anything about such rifles): https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/are-questions-about-items-for-collecting-on-topic

Comment: @imsodin I am looking in Texas.

Comment: @imsodin - if this is about collectables, is there an xSE where it would be more appropriate?

Comment: Even if it were a collectible, I fail to see how it would be in scope.

Comment: Perhaps re-word the question to be how to locate, or the best places to look for vintage gun parts and accessories? I'm not sure if that would be any better, just a thought

Comment: @NateW For me that too wouldn't bring it in scope. firearms.se got closed. weapons.se is still in definition stage. Either of those could be better fit than here.

Comment: @Ricketyship Weapons.se isn't going anywhere

Comment: Can we please stop debating whether firearms are on topic on TGO in comments. If you feel like it, open a meta, but we discussed it already several times with the result, that it should be on topic.

Comment: @imsodin No one is debating on if gun is in scope.  The question is if this is a shopping question.